# Uniform convergence of uniformly continuous functions implies uniform boundedness?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If a sequence of uniformly continuous functions on a compact set converge uniformly, is it true that the sequence is bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for $\|f_{n}-f\|_{\infty}\rightarrow 0$, then for some $N$, if $n\geq N$, $\|f_{n}\|_{\infty}\leq\|f\|_{\infty}+1$. Note that $f$ is also continuous by the uniform convergence. As $f$ is continuous on the compact set, so $\|f\|_{\infty}=\max|f|<\infty$. So $\|f_{n}\|\leq\max\{\|f_{1}\|_{\infty},...,\|f_{N-1}\|_{\infty},\|f_{N}\|_{\infty}+1\}$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. There exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have  $\sup_x|f_n(x) - f(x) |<\epsilon$ (conclude your self why this implies boundedness for $n>N$). Since $f_n$ is continuous we have for all $n\leq N$  there exist a $M_n$ such that   $|f_n(x) |<M_n$ for all $x$ in the domain by Weierstrass Maximum Theorem. Choose $M=\max_{n\leq N} \{M_n\}$ and such maximum exists (why?). Now put these things together an conclude.